# python 3.5 : if statement evaluates as true and does nothing, even if told to do something

Tags: python, debugging, python-3.5

heres a nightmare for you.. a complete malfunction of python3.5!

`print(value.time() > marketclosed)` prints True.

```
if value.time() > marketclosed:
   #somecode
```

Does not execute the code contained in the if statement.

currently its used in this context. no errors, not a peep from the compiler about this if statement. just.. nothing.

```
import datetime as dt
```

`for i in range(0,int(total_intervals)):`

```
    amount_to_add = dt.timedelta(hours=marketopen.hour,minutes=marketopen.minute) + dt.timedelta(seconds=interval_seconds)*i
    basevalue = start_datetime + amount_to_add
    value = basevalue
    print(value.time())
    print(marketclosed)
    print(value.time() > marketclosed)
    print(value.date())
    print(value.date().isoweekday())
    if value.time() > marketclosed:  # advance to next day
        value + dt.timedelta(days=1)
        value.combine(value.date(),marketopen)
```

its spooky.. its like the world grinds to a halt when someone is on the verge of greatness!

Comment: What is printed by each of those 5 print statements?

Comment: `value + timedelta(days=1)` does nothing indeed. You may want `+=` instead. Same regarding the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this code executes, it just does nothing, because the results of `value + timedelta` and `value.combine()` are discarded (they create a new object without mutating the original one). This should work:

```
if value.time() > marketclosed:  # advance to next day
    value += dt.timedelta(days=1)
    value = value.combine(value.date(), marketopen)
```

Pylint must report at least the `+` part as `W0104, pointless-statement`.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think that the code is not executed?

You reset 'value' each time to basevalue so you would not be able to see any effect from the calls in the 'if' statement.

Put a print line inside the 'if' statement to check if it is being executed.